# Splitting and iterative simple regression in r

Tags: r, regression, plyr

I am pretty much new to r and I have a dummy example of a bigger table underneath. I want to split the table based on id variable (a,b,c,d) and do iterative simple linear regression for every subset: x is my x variable, and columns 1:6 are y variables, I want to regress each of y1 - y6 against x, for each group to have 6 regressions per group and 24 sets of coefficients overall. Also, it would be great if I could output the model p values of the slopes into a new data frame.

```
    id x  1  2  3  4  5  6
1   a 74 18 19 NA 23 29  1
2   a 77 16 19 17 22 29  2
3   a 79 16 NA 19 23 29  3
4   a 81 17 20 18 23 29  4
5   b 74 19 20 19 23 28 11
6   b 76 15 19 18 26 28 12
7   b 79 19 21 20 24 28 NA
8   b 81 19 21 20 23 28 14
9   c 68 19 20 20 23 29  8
10  c 70 17 22 22 27 29  9
11  c 73 18 22 21 23 29 10
12  c 75 19 20 19 23 29 11
13  d 65 18 18 19 22 28  5
14  d 68 18 NA 18 20 29  6
15  d 70 18 19 18 23 28  7
16  d 72 19 17 19 22 28  8`
```

I tried to use plyr package but it didn't work out

```
for ( i in 3:ncol(dumm)){
regression[i] <- dlply(dumm, .(id), function(z) lm(dumm[,i]~dumm$x, z))
}
coefs <- ldply(regression, coef)
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What's your intended output? Also, this doesn't seem like a very good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using`by` and `lapply`:

```
by(dumm[-1], dumm$id, function(d) {
  lapply(d[-1], function(r) lm(r ~ d$x))
})
```

You can receive a summary together with the p-values with this command:

```
by(dumm[-1], dumm$id, function(d) {
  lapply(d[-1], function(r) coef(summary(lm(r ~ d$x))))
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much and also I want to have an ouput p values of the slope in a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> lapply(split(ddf, ddf$id), function(x) lapply(x[3:8], function(y) lm(y~x[[2]])  ))
$a
$a$X1

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x[[2]])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       x[[2]]  
    29.1028      -0.1589  


$a$X2

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x[[2]])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       x[[2]]  
     7.8378       0.1486  

....
```

or with summary:

```
> lapply(split(ddf, ddf$id), function(x) lapply(x[3:8], function(y) summary(lm(y~x[[2]]))  ))
$a
$a$X1

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x[[2]])

Residuals:
      1       2       3       4 
 0.6542 -0.8692 -0.5514  0.7664 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  29.1028    15.3196   1.900    0.198
x[[2]]       -0.1589     0.1969  -0.807    0.504

Residual standard error: 1.019 on 2 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2455,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.1317 
F-statistic: 0.6509 on 1 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.5045


$a$X2

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x[[2]])

Residuals:
      1       2       4 
 0.1622 -0.2838  0.1216 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  7.83784    5.43394   1.442    0.386
x[[2]]       0.14865    0.07022   2.117    0.281

Residual standard error: 0.3487 on 1 degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.8176,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6351 
F-statistic: 4.481 on 1 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.2809

...
```